# LiipImagineBundle: change the path where the images are saved after applying the filter

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle, php-imagine

I have this this config:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        subitem_in_category: 
            path: ~  ///how to change the default path where the images are saved?
            filters:
                my_custom_filter: { }
                relative_resize: { heighten: 210 }
```

Im trying to change the name of the directory wheren the images are saved, but I get

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "path" under
>   "liip_imagine.filter_sets.subitem_in_category"

I have read this: https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration.md

Answer (score 1):

The features was removed  some time ago for bad design about component dependency. [See this pull request for further motivations about this.](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/pull/366)

For the same features suggest to configuring several resolvers, as described [here](https://gist.github.com/makasim/9802395):

```
liip_imagine:
  resolvers:
      foo:
        web_path:
          cache_prefix: foo
      bar:
        web_path:
          cache_prefix: bar
  filter_sets:
    foo:
      cache: foo
    bar:
      cache: bar
```

Else you can use an old branch of the bundle.

Hope this help

Comment: BTW i will open a pull request on the documentation of the bundle asap